# Getting an error 500 internal server error

Tags: java, servlets

HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Class test.testing1 is not a Servlet

root cause 
java.lang.ClassCastException: test.testing1 cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet

Comment: Please include the relevant portions from your `web.xml` file along the code from the class which you believe to have configured as a servlet.

Comment: Your testing1 class is not implementing servlet interface directly or indirectly.

Comment: how to solve this problem

Comment: @DarshanAkumar, Please share your testing1 class code.

Comment: public class testing1 extends PDFTOEXCEL {    
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
             {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            out.println("converted sucessfully");        
        }
    }
   
}

Comment: this my servlet code

Comment: i have not extended http servlet i extended java class instead of that PDFTOEXCEL is my java class name

Comment: What is PDFTOEXCEL class, Is it implementing Servlet interface.

Comment: Try like this: `public class testing1 extends PDFTOEXCEL implements Servlet { ... }`

Comment: no it is normal java program

Comment: You need to override `service` method and call `processRequest` from service method

Comment: how to create service method???

Comment: Try like this: public class testing1 extends PDFTOEXCEL implements Servlet { ... } – DK Ansh 3 mins ago tried but still getting same error

Comment: See the answer, You need to override all the method of servelt interface and call `processRequest` from `service` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
public class testing1 extends PDFTOEXCEL implements Servlet {
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            out.println("converted sucessfully");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest((HttpServletRequest)req, (HttpServletResponse)res);

    }
}
```